# How to fetch distinct nodes in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

When applying the function `distinct-values()` to a sequence of nodes, it returns a sequence of values rather than a sequence of nodes.

Please can someone explain to me which feature of the XQuery data model makes it difficult to eliminate duplicate values directly on a sequence of nodes?

Also, how can this sequence of values be turned back into a sequence of nodes?

I've looked through my XML/XQuery notes and scoured the internet without finding explicit information.

Answer (score 5):

In XQuery, every node is distinct (it has an internal, unique node ID).

---

If you want to compare nodes, you will have to deep compare their values. There is no predefined function for this, but as this is a common problem, [FunctX](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/) contains one, [`functx:distinct-deep()`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_distinct-deep.html). It has a dependency on [`functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal()`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal.html), so you will need that, too.

```
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare function functx:distinct-deep 
  ( $nodes as node()* )  as node()* {

    for $seq in (1 to count($nodes))
    return $nodes[$seq][not(functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal(
                          .,$nodes[position() < $seq]))]
 } ;
declare function functx:is-node-in-sequence-deep-equal 
  ( $node as node()? ,
    $seq as node()* )  as xs:boolean {

   some $nodeInSeq in $seq satisfies deep-equal($nodeInSeq,$node)
 } ;
```

Alternatively you can [import the whole FunctX module](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/download.html), but this can slow down execution a lot depending on your XQuery interpreter.

---

If you don't want to stick with FunctX, you need to search all distinct values and for each find the first element (so the one without any preceding ones) and compare the `data()` to the distinct value.

```
for $value in distinct-values(//data())
return //*[data() = $value][every $preceding in preceding::node() satisfies name() != $preceding/name()]
```

In the end, this does the same as the FunctX-functions above do. You can use other constructs for some parts, but not omit any of these steps.

Comment: Hi Jen!  Thanks for your prompt reply.  Just to confirm: Every node is distict anyhow so applying the function distinct-value is problematic. I'm required to compare nodes to see if they are unique or not i.e. distinct but there is no predefined facility to do this in XQuery.  Please can you be clearer on how a sequence of values can be turned back into a sequence of nodes? Thanks M

Comment: Please tell us about your _real_ question. I don't think the problem you have to solve is getting distinct nodes, but something requiring this. Giving some input and expected output makes understanding your problem much easier. Please edit that into your question. Maybe also read about [how to provide a SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). The more specific you are, the more likely and faster you will get exactly the answer you need.

Comment: Hi again Jens! My real questions are as follows: First, When applying the function distinct-values to a sequence of nodes, it returns a sequence of values rather than a sequence of nodes. Briefly explain which feature of the XQuery data model makes it difficult to eliminate duplicate values directly on a sequence of nodes. and secondly: How can you turn this sequence of values back into a sequence of nodes?
Thanks

Comment: Want do you want to achieve with "turning this sequence of values back into a sequence of nodes"? There is no general solution for this, you must either present what you're really trying to achieve or go with the functions I gave above (which should do what you need).

Comment: @JensErat, What issue do you see in using the standard XPath function `deep-equal()` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are lots of ways to solve this problem, and `deep-equal` will be included in most reasonable ones, but isn't sufficient on its own. I don't think you're able to get something shorter than `//somenode[not(some $other in following::somenode satisfies deep-equal(., $other))]` which in the end is the same as the FunctX functions. Do you have another proposal?

Comment: Sorry about this, please can I get some clarity on my question? I need to know 1. What is the XQuery feature (making it difficult to eliminate duplicate values directly on a sequence of nodes)? and 2. How can you turn this sequence of values back into a sequence of nodes?  Forgive me for my lack of comprehension.

Comment: This was actually an exam question which has taken my interest and I'm trying to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the answers I've received are not explicit enough.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're getting unspecific answer because your question still is. _You're not giving us all information which is relevant_, thus we cannot provide better answers. For example, please state if you're looking for exam questions and give us _the exact question_. Usually people look for an answer to a "real problem", and we're proposing reasonable ones then. If you really need to go back from the values, you need to scan all elements again and compare the data inside. I added an example to my answer.